# How to know what device to pass SDP to across signaling server when establishing WebRTC connection

Tags: webrtc

Let's say I have an application that has a list of live streamers who are currently broadcasting via WebRTC. In order for a device to plug into a particular broadcaster, they need to send their SDP to the specific broadcaster that they click on.

So I gather my local SDP information, and send that to the Signaling server to be transferred to the broadcaster and await the answer.

My question is, how does the signaling server know which broadcaster to send this SDP to? And where do you store this identifier?

My first thought was use the ip address as the unique identifier but that can change as I move around and change connections.

And is it normal to store this identifier on the web socket itself as a property? I don't know how else you would know which web socket to send along the SDP?

Sorry if this is a n00b question, very new to WebRTC.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same situation like you.

In my case, I used Socket.IO for bidirectional communication.

So what I did is using member's id and socket.io's room.

When socket.io client connected to server, this client joined specific room automatically.

That room's name is client's socket ID. You can check this [doc](https://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/#Default-room).

For example, your service is broadcasting. right?

And maybe broadcasters in your service have unique id (in Database).

So when client is connected to server, escape from default room immediately, and join new room that name is client's unique id.

Then, now you can send some messages like sdp to [specific client with client's unique id](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#socket-to-room).